# I need to implement silent Notification using FCM

Tags: ios, iphone, push-notification

I already know that `content_available = true`  is used to do that.
But my problem is that i am getting silent notification while app is in foreground and background but not getting in terminate state

can anyone help me with this, why i am not getting when app is not running.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the app has been terminated, then it's not possible to re-launch the app from that state. From [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623013-application):

> However, the system does not automatically launch your app if the user has force-quit it. In that situation, the user must relaunch your app or restart the device before the system attempts to launch your app automatically again.